# Check if existing jQuery object (not a selector) exists in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**Example:**

```
var $doesNotYetExistInTheDOM = $('<span/>'); // create new jQuery element
                                             // outside of the DOM
var $doesExistInTheDOM = $('span');  // selected element from the DOM
```

Is there a way to check if a **jQuery** selected object exists in the **DOM**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by trying to find it in the document:

```
!!$(document).find($doesNotYetExistInTheDOM).length // false
!!$(document).find($doesExistInTheDOM).length // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this:

```
$('span').length // if exists it return > 0 or 0
```

if you want check using any particular `id` or `class` then try:

```
$('span.some').length
```

or

```
$('span#some').length
```

**Using you variable:**

```
var $doesNotYetExistInTheDOM = $('<span/>');

$(document,$doesNotYetExistInTheDOM).length

var $doesExistInTheDOM = $('span'); 

$(document,$doesExistInTheDOM ).length
```

jQuery has a method called **[`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size/)** (but `.length` is preferred)

**Use:**

```
$('span.some').size()

$('span#some').size()

var $doesNotYetExistInTheDOM = $('<span/>');

$(document,$doesNotYetExistInTheDOM).size()
```