# Check if JQuery object exists in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which expect from parameter JQuery object. I need to find if JQuery object exists in DOM or not (in `$('<div></div>')` case).

I check for duplicates and found several answers ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167030/check-if-existing-jquery-object-not-a-selector-exists-in-the-dom), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386419/how-to-check-htmlelement-object-exists-in-dom), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040715/check-if-cached-jquery-object-is-still-in-dom)). Can some expert shine some light witch is the best (fastest) way to do it.

Options are:

```
$.contains //not working
$a.find
$a.parent()
$a.closes()
document.contains()
$a[0].isConnected
```

Snippet:

```js
var a = $("#test"); //length 1
var b = $('<div></div>'); //length 1

console.log("contains: ", $.contains(document, a), $.contains(document, b)); //false, false
console.log("find: ", !!$(document).find(a).length, !!$(document).find(b).length); // true, false
console.log("parent: ", !!a.parent().length, !!b.parent().length); // true, false
console.log("closest: ", !!a.closest('body').length, !!b.closest('body').length);   //true, false
console.log("document.contains: ", document.contains(a[0]), document.contains(b[0]));   //true, false
console.log("isConnected: ", a[0].isConnected, b[0].isConnected);   //true, false
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If performance is a really big concern for you, native methods are generally the way to go.

```
document.contains($myJQueryEl[0])
```

Outperforms the next fastest jQuery operation, `$elem.closest('body')`, by around 4 times according to [this answer and its comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31168803/1008741).

If you're really looking for performance for non-document elements, however, [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) is definitely your best option.

Comment: @Makla you didn't mention browser compatibility as one of your requirements. If that's the case, then as I said above `$elem.closest('body')` is the next-fastest alternative. :)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use jQuery if you want best performance. You can try [`isConnected`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-isconnected):

> The `isConnected` attribute’s getter must return true, if [context
>   object](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#context-object) is [connected](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#connected), and false otherwise.
>
> An [element](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-element) is connected if its [shadow-including root](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-shadow-including-root) is a
>   [document](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-document).

```
$element[0].isConnected; // jQuery
element.isConnected; // Native JS
```

Comment: Hi, apparently isConnected does not work in Firefox 48.0 or IE 11.

Comment: @Makla Seems a new thing indeed, I had never noticed it until today. It works on Firefox 49.